# Replace character and swap with the next one in string.

Tags: php

i want to replace a char and want to put that character just after next char in php.
for example:

```
<?php
$exa = array("R" => "r", "A" => "a", "V" => "v", "I" => "i");
echo strtr("RAVI", $exa);
?> //displays "ravi" ok
```

i want to replace "V" with "v" and then want to put it after "I".
like this: "raiv"

Comment: Can I ask what practical use will this have?

Comment: That didn't really explain the purpose. What has messing up string to do with fonts?

Comment: i am not talking about string to lower function. i gave that just for example.because you dont know hindi.i want to convert all chars and want to put selected char just after its next char.

Comment: I don't think it's clear at all what you're asking...

Comment: What will happen if the replaced character is at the end? Or, if there are two next to each other?

Comment: there are 4 char in example but i will use more than 2000+ char in this program.its actually a converter.

Comment: You didn't answer. Those situations are not really clear.

Comment: Can you give a few more examples so we can see a "pattern"

Comment: @mightypork:- than result goes bad. but user will not put it in wrong order.

Comment: if they mistype its their problem not mine. can you write Hello World as heeelo wrold ?? no u wont.. same the user of this program will not mistype the language.if he does than result will go wrong.

Comment: @Ravikant check my answer, I think I cracked the nut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this solution might interest you:

**Function**

```
function replaceAndMove($text, $replacements) {

    $from = array_keys($replacements);
    $to = array_values($replacements);

    function fixFrom($s) {
        return '/' . preg_quote($s, '/') . '(.|$)' . '/';
    }

    function fixTo($s) {
        return '${1}' . $s;
    }

    $from_ready = array_map('fixFrom', $from);
    $to_ready = array_map('fixTo', $to);

    return preg_replace($from_ready, $to_ready, $text);
}
```

**Test Case**

```
$text = "abcdXefghXijklX----aFb~~~cMd";

$replacements = array(
    'X' => 'x',
    'F' => 'f',
    'M' => 'm',
);

echo $text . '<br>';
echo replaceAndMove($text, $replacements);
```

**Output**

```
abcdXefghXijklX----aFb~~~cMd
abcdexfghixjkl-x---abf~~~cdm
```

---

*Edit: Fixed problems with regex-special chars, such as . or ]*

Comment: @Ravikant when I answered, it wasn't really safe. It is now (edited) - should handle even characters that have special meaning in regex.

Comment: damnit yet another bug. I hope this new edit works good. If not, I will try to help again.

Answer (score 1):

do the str_replace first, then use strlen, substr and the index of the character string to replace the last 2 spots if that is what you are trying to do. Because you can access a string like an array each characters $t[1] == e if the string was "test"

If you have a few "set" patterns you could just do this:

```
$find = array('RAVI',...,so on);
$replace = array('raiv',..., so on);

$input = 'RAVI';

echo str_replace($find, $replace, $input);
```

Just add more set pairs to the arrays for more replacements... If that's all you want.

Comment: No, it is not. He apparently wants to do other strings, not only this example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
<?php

$string = "RAVIVL";
$replace_char = "v";
$string = strtolower($string);
$pos = array_keys(array_intersect(str_split($string),array($replace_char)));

foreach ($pos as $p) {

   if (isset($string[$p+1])) {
      $string[$p] = $string[$p+1];
      $string[$p+1] = $replace_char;

   }
}
echo $string;
?>
```

Swaps all occurrences o "v" with the following letter.

Comment: $string = "RAVIVP"; displays "raivvp" not "raivpv"